# how to print out the whole table using anonymous block in pl sql?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I want to use `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE`, but the number of rows exceeds just 1.  There is nothing in the table which increments sequentially, so I can't use a loop. Is there some way to print out each row in the table?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

try with something like this.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
     BEGIN
          -- A PL/SQL cursor
          FOR cursor1 IN (SELECT * FROM table1) 
          LOOP
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Column 1 = ' || cursor1.column1 ||
                               ', Column 2 = ' || cursor1.column2);
          END LOOP;
     END;
        /
```

Comment: how can I increment to cursor to move to next row?

Comment: You don't need to -- an implicit cursor like the one above fetches the next row automatically and exits when there's no more rows to fetch.

Comment: After wasting lot of time, I figured out your `FOR` LOOP should be inside `BEGIN -- END`

Answer (score 3):

This may help:

```
BEGIN    
  FOR MY_CURSOR IN (SELECT COLUMN1,COLUMN2,COLUMN3 FROM MY_TABLE) 
  LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('COLUMN1 = ' || MY_CURSOR.COLUMN1 ||', 
                          COLUMN2 = ' || MY_CURSOR.COLUMN2 ||',
                          COLUMN3 = ' || MY_CURSOR.COLUMN3);
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Answer (score 2):

The quick and dirtiest way of doing this is actually through SQL*Plus:

```
SQL>  set lines 200
SQL>  set heading off
SQL>  set feedback off
SQL>  spool $HOME/your_table.out
SQL>  select * from your_table;
SQL>  spool off
```

SQL*Plus has some neat if basic reporting functionality; we can even [generate HTML files](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch7.htm).

If you have a very long table (many rows) or a wide one (many columns) you may be better off outputting directly to a file, like this.

```
declare
    fh utl_file.file_type;
begin
    fh := utl_file.fopen('TARGET_DIRECTORY', 'your_table.lst', 'W');
    for lrec in ( select * from your_table )
    loop
        utl_file.put( fh, id );         
        utl_file.put( fh, '::' );         
        utl_file.put( fh, col_1 );         
        utl_file.put( fh, '::' );         
        utl_file.put( fh, col_2 );         
        utl_file.put( fh, '::' );         
        utl_file.put( fh, to_char ( col_3, 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss' ) );         
        utl_file.new_line(fh);         
    end loop;
    utl_file.fclose(fh);
end; 
/
```

This may look like a chore, but the PUT() calls can be generated from USER_TAB_COLUMNS.  There are a couple of gotchas with UTL_FILE so [read the documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/u_file.htm#BABGGEDF).

You *could* use the same control structure with DBMS_OUTPUT....

```
begin
    for lrec in ( select * from your_table )
    loop
        dbms_output.put( id );         
        dbms_output.put( '::' );         
        dbms_output.put( col_1 );         
        dbms_output.put( '::' );         
        dbms_output.put( col_2 );         
        dbms_output.put( '::' );         
        dbms_output.put( to_char ( col_3, 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss' ) );         
        dbms_output.new_line;         
    end loop;
end;
/
```

... but if you are going to spool out from a SQL*Plus, why not use the easier option?