# How to return table from anonymous block?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, plsql

I don't have write rights to db but I need to get result which cannot be taken using sql request.

So I need a procedure.

I can declare an anonymous block to execute right from console:

```
SQL> declare ... begin ... end;
```

I even can create custom table inside and put some data inside:

```
SQL> declare 
type RowType is record (column1 varchar(20), column2 integer);
type TableType is table of RowType;
resultTable TableType;
...
begin
...
execute immediate 'some dynamic request'
bulk collect into resultTable;
...
end;
```

but how can I view what's inside "resultTable"?

UPD: found this: [how to print out the whole table using anonymous block in pl sql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2348319/how-to-print-out-the-whole-table-using-anonymous-block-in-pl-sql)

But stil wasn't able to output data:

```
SQL> declare 
    type RowType is record (column1 varchar(20), column2 integer);
    type TableType is table of RowType;
    resultTable TableType;
    ...
    begin
    ...
    execute immediate 'some dynamic request'
    bulk collect into resultTable;
    ...
    FOR cursor1 IN (SELECT * FROM resultTable)                     --\
    LOOP                                                           --| this fails
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Column 1 = ' || cursor1.column1 ||     --|
                           ', Column 2 = ' || cursor1.column2);    --|
    END LOOP;                                                      --/
    end;
```

this causes `ORA-00942: table or view does not exist`

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to print out the whole table using anonymous block in pl sql?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2348319/how-to-print-out-the-whole-table-using-anonymous-block-in-pl-sql)

Comment: If only you read my question - you would see that I've already mentioned that question. No. It's not a duplicate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure if this is what you're asking about, but you can use [DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/oracle/bipack/ch06_01.htm) to view what's inside your `resultTable`, from the console.

**EDIT**: I've possibly butchered the syntax, but I think you can do something like this:

```
FOR indx IN 1 .. resultTable.COUNT 
LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Column 1 = ' || resultTable(indx).column1 || 
                         ', Column 2 = ' || resultTable(indx).column2);
END LOOP;
```

Comment: Yep I tried it. But I know only how to write "line", not the table. Any Ideas?

Comment: I've updated my question. It seems to be close to what you've suggested

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
declare 
type RowType is record (column1 varchar(20), column2 integer);
type TableType is table of RowType;
resultTable TableType;
...
begin
...
execute immediate 'some dynamic request'
bulk collect into resultTable;

FOR r IN 1..resultTable.count loop
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(resultTable(r).column1 || ' ' ||resultTable(r).column2);
end loop;
```

I hope this helps you.